# Python Reverse -Storing it to array(Fails)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i have this code that ask the user a number (123) and the output should be [3,2,1] but on my code below how is my reverse num not iterable??

```
def rev(Number): 
    new_arr = []
    Reverse = 0    
    while(Number > 0):    
        Reminder = Number %10    
        Reverse = (Reverse *10) + Reminder    # if the user has 123 the output of this is 321
        Number = Number //10  
    for i in Reverse:      # but when i loop it.. it has an error that int is not iterable
        new_array.append(i)
    return new_array
        
print(rev(123))
```

any idea how i can resolve this?

Comment: `def rev(Number) : return list(map(int,str(Number)[::-1])))`

Comment: Do you want to convert the number to a string while iterating?

Comment: In your own words, what do you think should happen when you try to take each element of the integer `321`? In your own words, why do you think it makes sense to say that a number has elements?

Comment: Omg. I forgot the simple syntax or basics.. You cant iterate an int.. Bruh! What happened to me.. Anyway thanks guys for answering :)

Comment: Hi @Codingisabusiness, can I kindly remind you to mark one of the solutions as answer so that this question is marked as answered?

Answer (score 1):

You assign value 0 to your `Reverse` variable. That means that Python will acknowledge `Reverse` to be type `int`, therefore not iterable. You'd have to convert it to a string, to be able to iterate through the single characters, or into a list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```py
new_array = list(map(int, str(Reverse)))
```

This will convert your integer to a string and then convert its digits to a list.

Comment: map() takes two parameters, a function and an iterable. Then we apply the function to all of the elements of the iterable. Strings are iterable in Python. What we do here is that we iterate through the string Reverse and apply int() function. int("1"), int("2") and so on. Then we get all of these integers and put into a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```py
input_val = "1234"
output_list = [int(val) for val in input_val[::-1]]
Output: [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

This will convert input value to reverse integer list.